# Spring AOP: How to invoke code before transactional method invocation, but after transaction begin?

Tags: xml, spring, transactions, aop, interceptor

We need to perform some operations just before any transactional method invocation (insert*, update*, ...), BUT - it's important - after the transaction begin.
We used to do it for years in that way:

```
    public class CustomBeginChangeAdvice implements MethodBeforeAdvice {
      @Override
      public void before(Method method, Object[] params, Object target) throws Throwable {
        (...)
      }
    }
```

```
    <bean id="beginChangeAdvice" 
      class="some.package.CustomBeginChangeAdvice" />

    <bean id="transactionProxyBase" abstract="true">
      <property name="postInterceptors">
        <list>
          <ref bean="beginChangeAdvice" />
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionProxy"
          parent="transactionProxyBase"
          class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean"
          abstract="true">
      <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager" />
      <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
          <prop key="insert*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
          <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
          <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly</prop>
        </props>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

but now, for some reason, we had to rewrite our XML configuration (we don't use annotations, it's an old system) in that way:

```
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="integrationTxManager">
      <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="insert*" />
        <tx:method name="update*" />
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="true" />
      </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
      <aop:pointcut id="beans" expression="(
        bean(firstLogic) || bean(secondLogic) || ...
      )" />
      <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="beans" />
    </aop:config>
```

and now we face the problem: how to make our beginChangeAdvice work as before, but without creating a custom proxy?

We've spent last few days on it, but couldn't find any working solution in Internet. The worst, there is very few info on an XML-like configuration.
Of course, most people use annotations today, but this is too much work for us to rewrite a whole system for now. It's pretty huge thing.
Is there anybody who could help us? Thanks in advance, Peter.

Comment: You can specify an `order` for the `aop:advisor`. You need to add both the tx one and your own advice and make sure they are ordered correctly.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your answer. Yes, this seems to work well, but I wonder if there is a better solution, because this one has some disadvantages. Mainly, the definition of transactional methods and beginChangeAdvice pointcut aren't the same and can be inconsistent. I think this is not very intuitive and can be difficult for other devs to maintain in the future. Is there any way to invoke beginChangeAdvice only for transactional methods? I mean, all listed as <tx:method name="..." />?

Comment: Only if you apply the same pointcut stuff (including the method names) to the your aadvice. Else use annotations as then you can just reuse the pointcut. I'm not sure what your advice/aspect is actually doing that it needs to be at that specific point. You can also write the code you have now in Java which will give you insight in what happens behind the scenes that way you could integrate easier with the aspect code.